# #DocuSignAPI unable to fetch Title in captive signing

Tags: docusignapi, signing, envelope

I have a document that requires signing by the clients, and the clients should be able to change their name and title.  I dragged and dropped the name field which is getting populated from the customize signature process and similarly I added the title field and hoped it would do the same.

However I tried the following it always turns up blank.  I am not able to prefill it using the following:

```
body = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">"
                    + "<emailSubject>API Call for adding signature request to document and sending</emailSubject>"
                    + "<status>sent</status>"
                    + "<documents>"
                    + "<document>"
                    + "<documentId>"+documentId+"</documentId>"
                    + "<name>" + documentName + "</name>"
                    + "</document>"
                    + "</documents>"
                    + "<recipients>"
                    + "<signers>"
                    + "<signer>"
                    + "<recipientId>1</recipientId>"
                    + "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>"
                    + "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>"
                    + "<clientUserId>" + planId + "</clientUserId>"
                    + "<title>CFO</title>" << 3rd Attempt
                    + "<tabs>"
                    + "<fullNameTabs>"
                    + "<fullName>"   // working perfectly                 
                    + "<xPosition>" + nameXPos + "</xPosition>"
                    + "<yPosition>" + nameYPos + "</yPosition>"
                    + "<documentId>"+documentId+"</documentId>"
                    + "<pageNumber>" + namePage + "</pageNumber>"
                    + "</fullName>"
                    + "</fullNameTabs>"     
                    + "<titleTabs>"
                    + "<title>"     // not pre-filling text              
                    + "<xPosition>" + titleXPos + "</xPosition>"
                    + "<yPosition>" + titleYPos + "</yPosition>"
                    + "<documentId>"+documentId+"</documentId>"
                    + "<pageNumber>" + titlePage + "</pageNumber>"
                    + "<name>GM</name><width>200</width>" << Tooltip works 
                    + "<value>General Manager</value>"  << Not working (bug?)
                    + "<tabLabel>General Manager</tabLabel>" << 2nd attempt
                    + "<required>false</required>"
                    + "</title>"
                    + "</titleTabs>"                         
                    + "<signHereTabs>"
                    + "<signHere>"
                    + "<xPosition>" + signatureXPos + "</xPosition>"
                    + "<yPosition>" + signatureYPos + "</yPosition>"
                    + "<documentId>"+documentId+"</documentId>"
                    + "<pageNumber>" + signaturePage + "</pageNumber>"
                    + "</signHere>"
                    + "</signHereTabs>"
                    + "</tabs>"
                    + "</signer>"
                    + "</signers>"
                    + "</recipients>"
                    + "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug in DocuSign.  This is the design of the captive recipient type.  Captive recipients aren’t known users in DocuSign, therefore the title does not exist.

The solution is very simple, you’d want to use a text tab and then prepopulate it’s value.

```
                + "<textTabs>"
                + "<text>"
                + "<xPosition>" + titleXPos + "</xPosition>"
                + "<yPosition>" + titleYPos + "</yPosition>"
                + "<documentId>"+documentId+"</documentId>"
                + "<pageNumber>" + titlePage + "</pageNumber>"
                + "<name>GM</name><width>200</width>"
                + "<value>General Manager</value>"
                + "<tabLabel>General Manager</tabLabel>"
                + "<required>false</required>"
                + "</text>"
                + "</textTabs>"
```